# Specified type member is not supported in linq to entities

Tags: linq, entity-framework, join, member

Hi hope someone can help.

I have an EF4 context with 2 POCO based entities that map on to 2 tables in a legacy SQL2005 database.  There are no relationships betwen the tables and no associations between the entity definitions in the context.

```
public class Venue
{
    public Venue(){}
    public string LocationCode {get;set;}
    public string LocationName {get;set;}
}

public class Booking
{
    public Booking(){}
    public string LocationCode {get;set;}
    public int EventReference {get;set;}
    public Venue BookingVenue {get;set;}
    public Event BookingEvent {get;set;}
}

public class Event
{
    public Event(){}
    public int EventReference {get;set;}
    public DateTime EventStart {get;set;}
    /* plus another 60 or so properties */
}
```

I can do a LINQ select from each individually but whenever I try and join between Event and Booking I get

The specified type member ‘BookingEvent’ is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

I've tried all the workarounds I can find across the web (there are no enums, calcualted properties, etc) and I'm more than a little frustrated now.

Help ?
Here's the query in question....

```
List<Booking> bookings = (from b in CalendarDB.Bookings
    join e in CalendarDB.Events join b.EventReference on e.EventReference
    select b).ToList();
```

Comment: can you show the code for the join in question?

Answer (score 0):

Without the relationships in the model, I don't think EF can figure out what data to use to join on. Even though your Booking class has a BookingEvent property, EF doesn't just 'know' that it needs to join on the Event table based on Booking.EventReference. Because of that, any query which attempts to use those reference properties will fail.

Comment: Sorry, I should have given an example of the LINQ query, it's pretty simple.  I've included it in the original question, as you can see it's just a manual join.